# Combine jquery fadeOut and scrollTop: doesn't fully fade

Tags: jquery, fadeout, scrolltop

I have placed a "Scroll Down" button at the bottom of my fullscreen gallery. (There is content below the fullscreen gallery.)

[Here's a link](http://www.matsmithphotography.com/mspv3) to my page so you can see for yourself.

My question isn't specific [Galleria](http://galleria.io/docs/), but this is what I'm using. I've therefore created a new element using the Galleria API, and appended it to the Galleria container.

Then I am using scollTop then fadeOut on this element (after adding an ID, further classes, and some HTML to the element):

```
this.$('scrollnote').attr('id', 'scrollnotecontainer').html("<h6>Scroll down</h6>").addClass('hide-for-touch').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollnotecontainer").offset().top
    }, 900);        
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

**The problem**: when you click on this "Scroll To" div, everything works as expected, but the element doesn't completely fade out.

As soon as I remove:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollnotecontainer").offset().top
    }, 900);
```

out of the picture (leaving fadeOut), the element does indeed fully fade out.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try doing this instead? The fade out will happen after scroll completes, in case something about doing both simultaneously is causing a problem:

```
this.$('scrollnote').attr('id', 'scrollnotecontainer').html("<h6>Scroll down</h6>").addClass('hide-for-touch').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollnotecontainer").offset().top,
        complete: function() { $(this).fadeOut(); }
    }, 900);        
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer was correct, however I am still having the same problem. This leads me to believe it is something else causing the element not to fade properly. I have no classes set on the elements that would cause this, although it could be something to do with the fact I'm also using foundation (foundation.zurb.com) on the page? Not sure though - as it does fade fine if I remove that scroll action!